# How to concatenate url('<front>') + string in Twig drupal

Tags: drupal, twig

I am trying to select a path that is equal to (http: // myweb / app) in html.html.twig of drupal.

For this, I'm using URL, but when trying to concatenate an array (which would be `url ('<front>')` with a string returns ArrayString) obviously this is wrong.

```
{% set url_app_front = url('<front>') %}
{% set url_app = url_app_front ~ 'app' %}
```

> Arrayapp

It is clear that `url('<front>')` is an array, but the #Markup that returns clean is http: / myweb /. I have tried to select it but... dont know how.

```
{{ url('<front>').markup }}
```

What I'm looking for would be something like ...

```
{% set url_app = url('<front>') ~ 'app' %}
{% set url = url('<current>') %}
{% if '{{ url_app }}' in url|render|render %}
```

To select http://myweb/app

If there is any other way to achieve it, I am also willing to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to convert this array to a string (thanks to #markup) with `render_var()`

I got it in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/243648/concatenate-url-in-twig (my bad for not looking there first)

```
{% set url_app = render_var(url('<front>')) ~ 'app' %}
{% set url = url('<current>') %}
{% if url_app in url|render|render %}
....
{% endif %}
```

> http://myweb/app